# Change the behavior of the "-browsecmd" callback from Tk::Tree

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

my problem is that the subroutine from "-browsecmd" is called twice, when a user clicks on an entry. It activates when the left mouse button is pressed and when it is released. Is it possible to tell "-browsecmd" to only activate once?

Here is an example script that demonstrates my problem. Whenever a user clicks on an entry the print function is called twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

use Tk;
use Tk::Tree;

my $mw   = MainWindow->new();
my $tree = $mw->Tree(
    -width     => '25',
    -browsecmd => \sub {
        my ($numbers) = @ARG;
        print $numbers. "\n";
    }
);

foreach (qw(one two three four five six )) {
    $tree->add( $ARG, -text => $ARG ); #populates the tree
}

$tree->pack();

MainLoop();
```

Thanks for reading my message.

EDIT1: Forgot to post the link to the [Tk::Tree Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ctdean/Tk-Tree-3.00401/Tk/Tree.pm#WIDGET-SPECIFIC_OPTIONS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's way to get rid of that behavior:

```
my $tree = $mw->Tree(
    -width     => '25',
    -selectmode => "single", # <= this makes it work
    -browsecmd => \sub {
        my ($numbers) = @ARG;
        print $numbers. "\n";
    }
);
```

Found this by browsing the doc for the parent widget: [`Tk::HList`](http://search.cpan.org/~ni-s/Tk800.015/pod/HList.pod) (the `BINDINGS` section is interesting).

Answer (score 2):

I've poked around and found that the Tk::Tree is really a Tix Tree under the hood. Digging around further finds a [tutorial](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/29485571/An-Introduction-to-Tix) with the following snippet (adapted very slightly):

> Example: “*my browsecmd gets called twice*”
>
> ```tcl
> tixScrolledListBox .list -browsecmd Browse
> proc Browse args {
>     if {[tixEvent type] ne "<ButtonRelease-1>"} {
>         puts "browsing [tixEvent value]"
>     }
> }
> ```

That looks highly relevant, but I don't see how `tixEvent` has been mapped into Perl. You might need to ask the Perl/Tk maintainer directly (or file a bug report).

Comment: My google-fu was good today; this was _not_ trivial to discover.